# EditText either editable or non editable and clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have a RecyclerView with the following items layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        ....
        android:clickable="@{viewModel.isClickable}"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onPropertyClicked}">

        <LinearLayout
            ....
            android:clickable="false">

            <TextView 
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                .... />

            <EditText
                ...
                android:text="@{viewModel.propertyValue}"
                android:focusable="@{viewModel.isEditTextClickable}"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="@{viewModel.isEditTextClickable}"
                android:cursorVisible="@{viewModel.isEditTextClickable}"
android:clickable="@{!viewModel.isEditTextClickable}"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView ... />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I want depending on a boolean the `EditText` to be either `editable` or `non-editable and clickable`. For some unknown reason, my `EditText` doesn't dispatch the touch event to the parent's parent. If I click on the `TextView` though, the `onClick` method is called.

If I specify the `onClick` of the `EditText` it works. I am wondering why though it doesn't work through the root ViewGroup's `onClick`.

I have tried many different things like

- Disable/Enable the `EditText` using `inputType`
- If `EditText` is non-editable and clickable set focusable to false and clickable to true
- Disable/Enable `EditText` using `enabled` true/false

It's really weird because the `EditText` is actually almost the same as the `TextView` that behaves as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to make android:clickable true at the second layout

Answer (score 0):

try to change this 
android:clickable="@{!viewModel.isEditTextClickable}"/>

for 
android:clickable="@{viewModel.isEditTextClickable}"/>